# Reduce the gap between Bio's in IEEEtran

Tags: spacing, ieeetran, biography

I am using this template for my paper:
https://www.overleaf.com/9944548wmfnwdynzwhg#/36502743/

I have a question regarding biography entries at the very end. As you can see in the template, there are big gaps between Michael Shell, John Doe and Jane Doe. We are only two authors in my paper at the last page, so this big gap does not look good, just like in the above example. Is there a way to lower it somehow? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Are you using `IEEEbiography` or `IEEEbiographynophoto`?

Comment: Its with photos

Comment: The link above is now broken; here's a copy of the template: https://www.overleaf.com/read/fcwqddvzfbmt

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just issue `\vskip 0pt plus -1fil` between the two `IEEEbiography` elements (to negative the inserted `1fil`). If you want them closer to one another, adjust `0pt` to something like `-2\baselineskip`.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me, especially \vskip -2\baselineskip plus -1fil

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me `\vskip -2\baselineskip plus -1fil`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).